# Sending a sudo command to RPI3 through Node-Red

Tags: node-red

I am making a data dashboard using Node-Red. My end goal is to use data from a motion detector to turn on and off the raspberry pi 7" display by sending: `sudo xset dpms force off` to the pi. I've tried exec node, but I can't find an example that closely matches my use case. I'm having no luck passing the command through the exec node so far.

I'd appreciate any help, thanks!

[image: screen of exec node]

**Correct command using script** thanks to @hardillb

[image: exec node]

I placed my script in /home/pi

[image: script]

Comment: Where are you setting the command and what errors are you getting?

Comment: You shouldn't need sudo in the script and in Node-RED (in fact you probably shouldn't need sudo at all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a thought, xset requires the DISPLAY env variable to be set and point to the active display.

If you are running Node-RED as a service then this variable is not going to be set.

Best bet is to create a short shell script to set the variable and run the command:

```
#!/bin/sh
export DISPLAY=:0.0
sudo xset dpms force off
```

and then point the exec node at the shell script.

Comment: I verified the script works in command, when I try and run it in node from exec i get this in debug; No protocol specified
xset:  unable to open display ":0.0"

Comment: ok, try it without the sudo, now I think about it you shouldn't need it (assuming both Node-RED and X is running as pi)

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!! This has been driving me nuts for 2 days. You are the man.

Comment: Just a slight correction to the above script it is: dpms just so others dont get stuck right here.